# Software updater has crashed

Tags: 14.04

Have been using 14.04 LTS for years with no problems. 
Have tried **sudo apt-get update** and get:

```
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```

Comment: As a new poster but long time Ubuntu User I upvoted your question and answer to give you more rep :). But sadly I had to vote your question as a duplicate :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually your system or apt is doing some work behind the scenes so when you try to access the `/var/lib[apt|dpkg]` and the system has a lock on this location you get those errors.

Now to see who or what is holding that lock you can run:

```
sudo lslocks | grep -E "/var/lib/dpkg/lock"
```

Answer (score 1):

Panic over, all seems to be working fine after I closed down and restarted.

Do not know why this has happened.